# In JavaScript, is there such an event as onCreate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm working with an existing system set up by someone else (no longer here).  In this system, clicking on the text within a special `<span>` will trigger a js function which will replace the text with an `<input>` field.  The text which was there is assigned as the `value` of the `<input>` element.

An `onblur` event is assigned to this new `<input>` field.  This calls a function which updates the data in the database via an AJAX call.  As part of this action, the `<input>` field is replaced with the new value (same `<span>` contents), and the onclick event is re-assigned.  In this way, you can click on the text, change it, click elsewhere, and it is automatically updated in the database.  Then you can do it again as it sets up the original events dynamically with each update.

It is in-between the first event and the second that I want access to that `<input>` field.  I want to add a jquery `.datepicker()` to it.

How would I go about calling `.datepicker()` on a dynamically-created element?

Comment: Couldn't you just update the "js function which will replace the text with an `<input>`" to bind the datepicker as well?

Comment: actual code would help also...

Comment: @mu: it's being used all over, in many scripts, for all text input fields.  but I only want to use it for one, so I don't want a calendar button after all those other input fields.  makes things a bit more complicated.  good idea, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't an event similar to an onCreate. The closest you can find is jQuery's .live(). This allows you to bind an event to an element now or in the future. I also think it will probably solve your problem.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

```
$('input').live('click', function() {
   $(this).datepicker();
});
```

As AutoSponge handily pointed out, live is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7. They suggest using on or delegate instead.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: But this probably won't work as it doesn't sound like there will be a click event triggered on the newly created `<input>`. There might be a focus event though...

Comment: live is deprecated, use delegate.

Comment: @AutoSponge - thanks. Looks like On and Delegate are the way to go now.

Comment: @muistooshort - agreed that click event may not be best for his case, but as delegate() can handle a number of events I figured he could choose the one that works best for him. Or perhaps programmatically trigger an event.

Comment: @mrtsherman: Actually using `.delegate()` is still preferred over `.live()` in case of older versions (where `.on()` is not available). It works in a more precise way.

Comment: @mrtsherman: yes, I thought of using delegate as well.  for some reason, it didn't work.  jquery was erroring out.  the js in this system is very strange, a mixture of standard js + jquery.  but that's not this issue, so I do think this is the best way to go.